# Learning Javascript: "this" keyword vs "arguments" object

Tags: javascript, arguments, this

Novice here, trying to grasp how `this` and `arguments` differ and in which circumstances one is used instead of the other?

For example, this prototype function will use `this` to perform some manipulation:

```
myObj.prototype.myFunc = function(){
  return this.(some manipulation); 
 }
```

Similarly, `arguments` is used to loop through each argument to be manipulated:

```
function myFunc() {
  for (var i = 0, i < arguments.length; i++){
    return arguments[i].(some manipulation)
  }
}
```

Basically in these two examples, the two seem interchangeable, in terms of being accessed as a parameter for further manipulation? I've been reading through various explanations here at Stack Overflow of each alone (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)), but in practice, I'm still quite confused as to which to use when it comes to application/context. When I do searches on the search engines, the "this" is often misunderstood or ignored, likely because of the frequency of its appearance...

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: `this` and `arguments` are completely unrelated. Your two functions operate on completely different things. Learn about them independently, don't try to relate them to each other.

Comment: arguments will help you get the arguments passed to function and "this" will help you find out the context of method.

Answer (score -1):

`this` is the object on which the function was invoked. For example, if you called a function `myObj.foo()`, within the scope of `foo`, `this` would refer to `myObj`. The value of `this` can sometimes be tricky. For example, say you did this:

```
var fooFn = myObj.foo;
fooFn();
```

In this case, `this` wouldn't refer to `myObj`, but rather to the global window object.

That's `this` in a nutshell.

As for `arguments`, it is an *array-like* object (not a true array) of all the arguments passed to the function. Suppose you have a function `function myFn(foo, bar)`. You can pass more than two arguments to `myFn`. If you called `myFn(1, 2, 3)`, how would you access the third argument? That's what `arguments` is for. In this case, `arguments` would have 3 elements: 1 (corresponding to the `foo` parameter), 2 (corresponding to the `bar` parameter), and 3 (the extra parameter).

You can make use of the `arguments` object to support overloaded versions of functions.

Comment: I appreciate the input, regardless! It's a great starting point for a beginner like me. From my perspective, when I see empty a function with empty parentheses for arguments, I'm inclined to think "should I be using `arguments` or `this` here...

Comment: The `arguments` object has 0-based indices, but your second-to-last paragraph suggests otherwise.

Comment: What? The arguments 1, 2, 3 are values, not indices. I assumed I didn't need to specify that it was zero-based indexing, since I did say it was an array-like object.